how to push an old reseted or reverted heads
I can go back and forward in my history using git checkout heads git revert heads git reset heads
And when I do git push origin main I get Everything up-to-date and no change on remote server.
how to solve it?
BTW Im pushing to this repository BKazimy and I want to go back to my second commit in history.
I tried:
git push origin main
git push -u origin main
git push -f origin main
git push -u -f origin main

All had same response Everything up-to-date and no change on remote.

Do not check anything else out. You need to be on your branch and then hard reset the branch pointer to the commit you want to go back to. You would say
git switch main
git reset --hard 3e295a5
git push -f origin main

Note that the more recent commits (the children of 3e295a5) will eventually die if you don't act to preserve them.

Here's what your current actions do:

git checkout HEAD: Restores the working directory files to match the state of the current commit.
git revert HEAD: Reverts the most recent commit.
git reset HEAD directly followed by ^ or ~1: Moves to the previous commit and optionally changes the working directory based on the reset mode. The ~1 version keeps the changes staged. The ^ version undoes changes to match that commit.

This means you are not going back far enough in your history.
What you may wanna try instead is git reset .

git reset --hard 3e295a5a16e63516a189ad168e68dc69dc4fb892 (or just 3e295a5) will force the branch (and working directory) to match the state of the specified commit. Be cautious, as this will delete any changes made after the reset commit.
Now use git push -f origin main to force push your changes and overwrite history.


I appreciate the time you invested and the information you provided, though it happened that matt's answer worked, and I thank him for that.
